# Mysql stored procedure giving error at runtime

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1312

I have created a stored procedure in Mysql, as :

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists test9$$
Create procedure test9(test_type varchar(20))
Reads sql data
begin

    Declare 1_id int;
    Declare 1_date varchar(20);
    Declare done int default 0;
    Declare cur1 cursor for 
        select id,name from buyers where ticket_type='test_type';
    Declare Continue handler for not found set done=1;

    Create temporary table if not exists ticketninja.history2(n_id int,n_date varchar(20));

    Open cur1;
        hist_loop:loop
            fetch cur1 into 1_id,1_date;

                if done=1 then
                    leave hist_loop;
                end if;

        insert into ticketninja.history2(n_id ,n_date) values(1_id,1_date);
        End loop hist_loop;
    close cur1;

    select * from history2;
    drop table history2;

End;

$$

delimiter ;
```

but when i call it using,

```
call test9('platinum');
```

it returns an error saying :

```
#1312 - PROCEDURE ticketninja.test1 can't return 
a result set in the given context
```

what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an OUT variable (see first code sample [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html))

Comment: even with OUT variable its not working i have made changes in the following manner :
Create procedure test9(out test_type varchar(20))